# can't backup postgres 13 with pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to backup a postgresql 13 database with the following command on MacOS:

```
PGPASSWORD=“my_password” /Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin/pg_dump -h xx.xx.xx.xx -p 5432 -U postgres dbname > my_backup.backup
```

I get the following error:

```
pg_dump: error: connection to database "dbname" failed: could not initiate GSSAPI security context:  The operation or option is not available: Credential for asked mech-type mech not found in the credential handle
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I'm looking up this error on google but I didn't found the solution yet. I'm providing the correct password, because I can connect to the host with this username/password-combination through pgadmin 4.

It's a Google Cloud Platform SQL Instance.

Anyone who knows the solution?

Comment: Do you really have "smart" quote marks in your shell command?

Answer (score 0):

For supplying credentials to *any* PostgreSQL utility, I would *strongly* recommend using the [Postgres Password File](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/libpq-pgpass.html) instead of trying to pass passwords around in variables.

Why?  You have to get those values *from* somewhere, which inevitably leads to them being left lying around in a *file* somewhere.  If that's the case, then why not use the [de facto standard] one that PostgreSQL *itself* already works with?
There is *no value* to be gained in reinventing the wheel here.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to the cluster as the `postgres` user. Which you should not have access to and which should not be available over the network.

It appears that you are trying to create a logical backup of a single database in the cluster; which means you should connect as the owner of that database.

Can you connect to the database using `psql`? Is a useful check.